# access local variable from outsie it scope c++

Tags: c++, function, variables

i have a function (trackObject) that has local variables(posX and posY).

and inside that function there are two function call that depends on those 2 variables.(checkIntersection and checkHit).

If i compile the program, the program run well but laggy.

I want to call those 2 function outside trackObject, but those two local variables can't be accessed.
I want to access it, but i don't know how.

I try to make those variables global, but making those variables global  make another variables(moments, moment10, moment01,and area) have to set to global too.

But when i do that, i get Heap Corruption exception.

Anyone know how to do it ? Or there are another solution for this ?

Here's my code

```
void trackObject(IplImage* imgThresh){
    // Calculate the moments of 'imgThresh'
    CvMoments *moments = (CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));
    cvMoments(imgThresh, moments, 1);
    double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0);
    double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1);
    double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0);

     // if the area<1000, I consider that the there are no object in the image and it's because of the noise, the area is not zero 
    if(area>1000){
        // calculate the position of the ball
        int posX = moment10/area;
        int posY = moment01/area;        

       if(lastX>=0 && lastY>=0 && posX>=0 && posY>=0)
        {
            // Draw a yellow line from the previous point to the current point
            cvLine(imgTracking, cvPoint(posX, posY), cvPoint(lastX, lastY), cvScalar(0,0,255), 4);

        }
        checkIntersection(300, lastY, posY);
        checkHit(posX,posY,lastX,lastY,startLineX, startLineY, endLineX, endLineY);
        lastX = posX;
        lastY = posY;
    }
    cvLine(imgTracking,cv::Point(100,300) , cv::Point(600,300),cv::Scalar(0,200,0),2,8);
    cvLine(imgTracking,cv::Point(100,400) , cv::Point(168,400),cv::Scalar(255,0,122),8,8);
    cvLine(imgTracking,cv::Point(171,400) , cv::Point(239,400),cv::Scalar(255,0,122),8,8);
    cvLine(imgTracking,cv::Point(241,400) , cv::Point(309,400),cv::Scalar(255,0,122),8,8);
    cvLine(imgTracking,cv::Point(312,400) , cv::Point(380,400),cv::Scalar(255,0,122),8,8);
    cvLine(imgTracking,cv::Point(383,400) , cv::Point(451,400),cv::Scalar(255,0,122),8,8);
    cvLine(imgTracking,cv::Point(454,400) , cv::Point(522,400),cv::Scalar(255,0,122),8,8);
    cvLine(imgTracking,cv::Point(525,400) , cv::Point(600,400),cv::Scalar(255,0,122),8,8);
    free(moments); 
}
```

Comment: First, why are you using malloc(), and especially in a C++ program?  You don't even need to dynamically allocate memory for "moments".  Just declare one locally and pass the address of it in your functions.

Comment: What's wrong with passing the values as arguments as you already do?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is it wrong ? what should i do then ?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld the program getting laggy

Comment: @Kevin pythagoras - There is no need to dynamically allocate memory for "moments".  Again, declare one locally, and just pass the address of it to your functions.  Secondly, since I don't know what CvMoments is, using malloc() will be wrong if it is a non-POD type.

Comment: @Kevin pythagoras -- it may be "laggy" because of the unneeded call to malloc() and free().  If you're calling your trackObject function many times, needless calls to the heap manager as you're doing now can slow your application down.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes i called it many times. So what i should use beside malloc ?

Comment: @Kevin pythagoras -- Do you know what it means to declare a local variable?  

    `CvMoments moments;  // no need for malloc()`

Once you do that, then you pass the address of moments to those functions you're calling.  No need for malloc() and free().

Comment: @Kevin phytagoras: Why do you think make the variables global would make the program less laggy? Did you run it in a profiler?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld because i want to make an If conditional branching inside trackObject(), but it getting laggy when i do that. 

I think it's laggy because of that

Comment: @Kevin pythagoras - Make the changes I suggested.  There is also another answer given to you that asked you to make the same changes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i try your suggestion  and don't use malloc but it's not working. the cvMoments(imgThresh, moments, 1); can't access variable moments.
And the other change in below answer give me error argument of type "lpllimage **" is incompatible with parameter of type "lpllimage *"

Comment: @Kevin pythagoras -- all you needed to do is take that very same function, and make no other changes except the ones I specified.  That function should work the same way with the only exception being that the moments variable is no longer a pointer and is no longer dynamically allocated, slowing things down (see my detailed answer below).

Comment: wow, thank you @PaulMcKenzie. it work more smoothly right now. Thank you for your help. I'm sorry for not understanding what do you say earlier, i know nothing about pointer before. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make less "laggy" by removing calls to malloc() and free():

```
void trackObject(IplImage* imgThresh){
    CvMoments moments;
    cvMoments(imgThresh, &moments, 1);
    double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments, 1, 0);
    double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments, 0, 1);
    double area = cvGetCentralMoment(&moments, 0, 0);
    //...
```

Note the declaration of the CvMoments local variable, and then all that is needed is to pass the address of this local variable to the functions that require a pointer to CvMoments.

Answer (score 2):

Copy them to variables of the calling function by using pointers:

```
void trackObject(IplImage* imgThresh, int *pX, int *pY)
{
    ...

    *pX = moment10 / area;
    *pY = moment01 / area;

    ...
}
```

The calling function will need some `int`s to store these values:

```
IplImage imgThresh;
int copyX, copyY;

trackObject(&imgThresh, &copyX, &copyY);
```

Comment: my function call for now is like this, 
trackObject(imgThresh);
but when i add copyX and copyY, it get error

Comment: @Kevinphytagoras Well the function call should look like `trackObject(&imgThresh, &copyX, &copyY)`, as FiddlingBits said. And your function signature will need to change to match.

Comment: i've got error argument of type "lpllimage **" is incompatible with parameter of type "lpllimage *"

Comment: @FiddlingBits i have implement your solution but still got incompatible error, and does changing  *pX = moment10 / area;
    *pY = moment01 / area; make me have to change the entire posX and posY ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with performance, it is probably due to the line:

CvMoments *moments = (CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));

If `trackObject()` is called frequently, `malloc` is expensive to call repeatedly.

Comment: Yes, the trackObject is called frequently, so what the other method than malloc ?

Comment: Either make it static or make it local.